# Simple question about variance

Tags: r, variance

I always thought I understood the concept of variance, but this one confuses me.

$
\begin{eqnarray}
X & := & (1, 2, 3)\\
E(X) & = & (1 + 2 + 3) / 3 = 2\\
Var(X) & = & Cov(X, X) = E((X - E(X))^2)\\
& = & E((-1, 0, 1)^2)\\
& = & E(1,0,1)\\
& = & 2/3
\end{eqnarray}
$

But `R` tells me that

```
> var(c(1,2,3))
[1] 1
```

**Which part of my calculation is wrong?**

Comment: You gave the formula for population variance. Sample variance is scaled by a factor of $\frac{n}{n-1}$, which adjusts for the fact that the sample is closer (in squared-deviation sense) to the sample mean than it is to the population mean; this fact imposes a downward bias on $n$-denominator sample variance estimates. As such, the unbiased version of sample variance is used very widely. see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Population_variance_and_sample_variance). So R's answer will be 3/2 times as big as if you just apply the population-variance definition to a sample.

Comment: To clarify - your calculation isn't exactly *wrong*, since it's perfectly valid to use that for a sample variance -- but the usual convention is to apply the $n-1$ denominator for a sample variance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the details of `?var` we find:

> The denominator n - 1 is used which gives an unbiased estimator of the
>   (co)variance for i.i.d. observations.

so you should have $2/2=1$ instead. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sample_variance) for some more details.